# Collections.sort on an arrayList

Tags: java, sorting, collections

here is my problem : i'm trying to use Collections.sort and I think nothing happens.
Parts of my code :

```
class MyArray

private ArrayList<MyVar> array;

public void sortUp()
{
    Collections.sort(array);
}

class MyVar implements Comparable<MyVar>

private int value;

public int compareTo(MyVar v)
{
    return value - v.value;
}
```

So my code is really big so i tried to put minimum, what i wanted it to do is : when i call sortUp i want array to be sorted by MyVar.value. It doesn't do anything and i don't know where it comes from.

PS: couldn't find in help how to make a drop-down thing, could you tell me so i can put most of my code?

Comment: Can you post the printed values of the list before and after `Collections.sort()` runs?

Comment: Hmm this was a mistake, my array was sorted, but this wasn't refreshed on the screen, my bad. Sorry about that, i thank you making me realize where i failed.

Comment: I'm glad you solved your own problem, as you didn't give us enough information to help you.  Next time, give us enough code to try it out for ourselves, the expected output, and the actual output.